# WPF C# Getting error when moving back and forth b/w Two Combo boxes items selection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have 02 combo box as shown [Combo Boxes]
When i move back and forth for selection of items b/w Combo Boxes(Category and Model No.) i get the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmS7B.png)

My C# sharp code is given below

```
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            string CmdString = "select ProductID from Product where ModelNo='" + comboModel.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Product");

            sda.Fill(dt1);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
            {
                txtProductID.Text = dr["ProductID"].ToString();
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Please type words for the error not just link to a picture - not all of us can or will chase down pictures for errors - you should also let us know exacty which line throws the error

Comment: The error is "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is opened."

Comment: Use `using`, it's much safer than manually disposing connections.

Comment: The line "con.open" throws the error. In the code i am filling the text box with combo box item selection and when move back and forth b/w 02 combo box items selection, i get the above said error.

Comment: now get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `con.Open();`.  Obviously the connection was already open from an earlier operation somewhere else or a prior run of this code.

That being said, you should probably not be keeping connections open unless you  need them, because you run the risk that they aren't ever closed properly.  You should use the disposable pattern, like this:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(myConnStr))
{
    // do your query, etc.
}
```

This will automatically close the connection and dispose of the resources.

Comment: now get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is opened somewhere else. Try putting it into using block, this way it will be disposed of automatically and is best practice for connections:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string CmdString = "select ProductID from Product where ModelNo='" + 
    comboModel.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Product");

    sda.Fill(dt1);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
    {
        txtProductID.Text = dr["ProductID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: now get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: At what line? Did you define connectionString?

Comment: at the start of the name space just before InitializeComponent()

Comment: You've probably deleted something you houldn't, but without seeing complete code with place where the error appears, noone can help